# "Объем средств, предусмотренный..." или "объем средств, предусмотренных..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, причастия

Как будет правильно:

*объем средств, предусмотренный в бюджете*

или

*объем средств, предусмотренных в бюджете*?

И какое правило русского языка разъясняет это?

Answer (score 4):

**Ответ изменен с учетом полученных замечаний.**

В данном случае возможны **оба варианта написания:**

(1) объем средств, **предусмотренный** в бюджете;

(2) объем средств, **предусмотренных** в бюджете.

Окончательный выбор можно сделать **с учетом контекста**.

У Розенталя есть правило на эту тему: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

4. В зависимости от значения возможно **различное согласование причастий.** Ср.: Часть книг, предназначенная для выставки, уже получена (получены все книги, предназначенные для выставки). – Часть книг, предназначенных для выставки, уже получена (получены не все книги, предназначенные для выставки).

Такие варианты согласования встречаются в тех случаях, когда **причастный оборот определяет не отдельное слово, а словосочетание.**

Ср. также: **количество электроэнергии, потребляемое...** (подчеркивается количественная сторона) – **количество электроэнергии, потребляемой...** (характеризуется объект, о части которого идет речь);

**В примерах на данную тему**  встречается согласование по существительному "средства":

Бюджетные ассигнования — предельные объемы денежных **средств, предусмотренных** в соответствующем ..

Методика определения общего объема **средств, предусмотренных** в федеральном бюджете...

Comment: Почему неверно "объем (какой), предусмотренный в бюджете"?

Comment: Во-первых, по правилу Розенталя; во-вторых, по смыслу (предусматривают, как я думаю,  средства в определенном объеме, а не объемы): в-третьих, я проверила сочетание по практическим текстам.

Comment: 1. Как догадаться какое правило Розенталя Вы имеете в виду? Если то, что в ответе, то оно говорит, что оборот не должен включать в себя определяемое слово, а это к делу не относится.  2. По смыслу из отрывка ничего не ясно, нужно видеть полное предложение.  3. "По практическим текстам" – тут я согласен.

Comment: У Розенталя сказано, что обособленный оборот должен стоять после определяемого слова. Это не так? То есть он может находиться на расстоянии от оборота?

Comment: Он (оборот) может находиться на разумном расстоянии от определяемого слова. Сравните: "слова  Sharon, свидетельствующие о...", и "слова  Sharon, свидетельствующей о..."

Comment: Разумность расстояния желательно, конечно,  обозначить (существует ли правило на эту тему?). Кроме того,  Розенталь всегда советует избегать смысловой неоднозначности, а здесь  два существительных,  каждое из которых может быть определяемым словом.

Comment: Когда такая фраза написана, неоднозначности нет. Неоднозначность в голове у автора, когда не знает, что хочет сказать.

Answer (score 2):

Вряд ли может быть правило. Откуда ему взяться? Только логика.
Чтобы правильно согласовать, надо решить, что именно в конкретном случае предусмотрели. Объём? Средства?
Предлагаю чуть заменить слова. Так понятнее.
"Количество денег".
Итак, можем ли мы сказать "денег, предусмотренных"? Нет, чушь выйдет. Тут они употреблены, как слово "море" в счетании "капля моря". Речь о конкретной мере (объём, капля, количество) чего-то абстрактного и не измеряемого в контексте ситуации, а значит и не предусматриваемого. 
Так что и разговор ведется предметно, об объеме, а не о некой единице измерения, будь то деньги, море или средства.
Поэтому "объём средств, предусмотренный". И никак иначе. 
На счёт ссылки на Розенталя уточню, что там не сказано "СРАЗУ после определяемого слова". Там написано не это. Розенталь говорит, что если оборот в тексте где-то после определяемого слова, то он обособляется, а если где-то до, то не обособляется.

Answer (score 1):

В переводе на "нормальный" язык объём средств" — это и есть количество денег.

***...количество денег, предусмотренное в бюджете = объем средств, предусмотренный в бюджете*** или ***...количество денег, предусмотренных в бюджете = объем средств, предусмотренных в бюджете***, согласование возможно как с количеством/объёмом, так и с деньгами/средствами.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Я вижу, что Вы изменили суть ответа: в ответе было сказано, что возможен один вариант, а Вы добавили, что допустимы оба варианта. Если М_Г согласен с Вашей правкой, тогда я сниму свой минус.

Comment: Гриззлик, я не читала другие ответы, а этот мне попался в очереди на низкокачественные; из вариантов, что с ним делать, я выбрала "править". А М_Г такой трепетный, он сразу удаляет свои ответы, ежели к ему чипляться.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо слишком длинного комментария (поскольку у нас обычно принято объяснять, за что ставят минусы).

Поддержал ответ Sharon (в исправленной редакции), который не только не вызывает у меня никаких сомнений, но и подтверждён понятными объяснениями, а также ссылками на источники. Соответственно, поставил минусы участникам, которые продублировали одни и те же аргументы, не выдерживающие, на мой взгляд, никакой критики.

По существу вопроса. Приведу ещё пример в дополнение к ответу Sharon. Рассмотрим две ситуации: (а) при подготовке бюджета выделили сумму денег (= предусмотрели объём средств) на социальные нужды, а затем эту сумму распределили по некоторым статьям бюджета, относящимся к "социалке"; (б) в бюджете выделили деньги на каждую статью, относящуюся к социалке, а затем всё это просуммировали.

Тогда в варианте (а) речь идёт о **сумме денег, выделенной** на социалку, а в варианте (б) — о **сумме денег, выделенных** на социалку.